# Haskell Function not accepting argument

Tags: haskell

I wrote a simple code to convert rgb to cmyk. Then I defined the datatype `Color`.
now I got this error:

```
Couldn't match expectet type `Color' with actual type `(t0, t1, t2)'
```

I thought `Color` would refer to `Rgb(Int,Int,Int)`. What I have done wrong?

My code:

```
data Color = Rgb (Int,Int,Int) | Cmyk Double Double Double Double deriving (Show)

rgb2cmyk :: Color -> Color
rgb2cmyk (Rgb (0,0,0)) = (Cmyk 0 0 0 1)
rgb2cmyk (Rgb (r,g,b)) = (Cmyk c m y k)
    where 
            rd = (fromIntegral r)/255
            gd = (fromIntegral g)/255
            bd = (fromIntegral b)/255
            w = max3 rd gd bd
            c = w - rd/w
            m = w - gd/w
            y = w - bd/w
            k = 1 - w

max3 :: Double -> Double -> Double -> Double
max3 a b c  | a>=b && a>=c  = a
            | b>=a && b>=c  = b
            | otherwise     = c

test1 = rgb2cmyk 233 123 123
```

Error occours in `test1` line. Do I have to write `rgb2cmyk $ Rgb`?

Comment: It looks OK to me. Which line exactly is it complaining about? Can we see the rest of the where-block?

Comment: Are you sure you aren't calling `rgb2cmyk (233, 123, 123)`? I would expect that to cause the error you're reporting. You need to construct a `Color` value e.g. `rgb2cmyk (Rgb (233, 123, 123))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to keep the syntax, keep `Rgb Int Int Int` instead of `Rgb (Int,Int,Int`)

```
data Color = Rgb Int Int Int | Cmyk Double Double Double Double deriving (Show)

rgb2cmyk :: Color -> Color
rgb2cmyk (Rgb 0 0 0) = (Cmyk 0 0 0 1)
rgb2cmyk (Rgb r g b) = (Cmyk c m y k)
    where 
    (...)


*Main> rgb2cmyk $ Rgb 0 0 0
Cmyk 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0
```

**Explaining the comment:**

You cant call `rgb2cmyk` as `rgb2cmyk x y z`, the function is expecting an `Rgb x y z` so you must call it as `rgb2cmyk Rgb 10 10 10` for example. `Rgb` is a `Color` is a constructor and either `Rgb` or `Cmyk` must be called if your function takes a `Color`.

Comment: Thank you! But is it possible to test without `$ Rgb` ?
I got my error by: `test1 = rgb2cmyk 233 123 123`

Comment: adding explanation about this @04k

Comment: @04k: You apparently forgot the parens. You defined `Rgb (Int, Int, Int)` as a constructor accepting a 3-tuple of ints, so pass them: `Rgb (233, 123, 123)`. The answer suggests to remove them. If you don't want `$`, use `rgb2cmyk (Rgb ...)`.

Comment: Thank you! Everything is fine now!